# Установка Monjaro openbox

Tags: linux

После установки Monjaro openbox и перезагрузки вижу следующую картину, что с эти делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А через SuperGrubDisk загрузка происходит?

Comment: Странно, но попробовал убрать разметку разделов на харде с помощью gparted и потом переставить os, и все получилось))