# вместо запуска ubuntu показывается gnu grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Ноут резко дернули и он отключился, после включения (ему для включения обязательно требовалось подключение к питанию, иначе никакой реакции) сразу появился grub. [image: вот что показывается при включении]

На ноуте рядом стоят убунту и винда7

Comment: Логическая структура дисков побилась, вероятно.

Comment: Уже было: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476418/

Comment: @donRumata только там ничего не было о том, что же делать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, тот вопрос, естественно, не имеет сюда никакого отношения, а делать надо то же самое, что и при любом (предположительном) повреждение диска: проверить, и если повреждён, поменять.

Comment: О чем речь и веду.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, нет, в каменте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476418/#comment541729_476418 сказано, что всё заработало. Просто ОП не оформил это как ответ. Способ не изящный, но сработал.

Comment: @donRumata отличный способ, также можно и новую машину купить.

Comment: так чем дело закончилось?

Comment: Я в итоге запустил убунту через флешку, удалил grub и все заработало, правда вместе с тем и файлы удалились